# Show that crossing number of Petersen graph must be >1?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

*Is there a way to show, that crossing number of Petersen graph must be > 1, without explicitly using Euler's formula (using girth, size and order of the graph)?*

(Like, for example you can do with K_6 graph, when you show, that if K_6 would have 2 crossing and if one would remove the vertex common to both of the crossing, one would supposedly get a K_5 without crossing, which is a contradiction.)

( background: I showed that GP(5,2) can not be planar using Euler's formula, and found the representation of it with two crossing, now I just need to show, that there can not be only one crossing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Any cycle divides the plane into two sections, inside and outside. Given two disjoint cycles, $C,C'$, if one vertex of $C$ falls inside $C'$ and one falls outside $C'$ then you are guaranteed two crossings between the cycles.

You need to show that no matter how you move around points of the Peterson Graph in the plane, there are two cycles for which this property holds.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see exactly how this helps me? Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: @Sara Find two cycles within the Peterson graph that have the relation I described, and then you'll have proven what you want to show.

Comment: I can find two cycles with the relation, but shouldn't then there be an argument that one is unable to find two disjoint cycles without this relation? (Or am I perhaps misinterpreting the term disjoint cycles (two cycles that do not share a common vertex))?

Comment: @Sara I don't know why you think that this relation necessarily would hold for every pair of cycles. It only need hold for two (and in fact there are non-intersecting cycles. That is the proper definition of "disjoint"

Answer (score 2):

If you know the theorems of Kuratowski and Wagner: Assume the Petersen graph has crossing number 1, then construct a new graph from a drawing that verifies this fact by introducing a new vertex at the crossing.
Note that this graph has one crossing fewer than the original graph.
If you can show that this graph is not planar by finding a $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ Minor you showed that the crossing number is strictly larger than 1.